# Trigger an event in jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my code structure, that I saw from someone else and am trying to make sense of it. I believe its a closure style and not a plugin style? maybe someone can clarify this for me if its a closure style.

Kind of plugin style. Here are some general questions.

1. So the variable NP is in the global namespace correct? and just used
   as a reference to the closure and its inner public methods.
2. Using NP (which is the namespace ) before a method is just a way to
   reference that method from outside the closure.
3. If I set NP to null does it destroy and allow for garbage collection
   of everything inside of NP including all variables.

This is the bigger question here so I'll put it out on its own.
When I trigger an event from an inner method **actionMethod()**
I want to be able to receive that event, from lets say another js file. For example home.js

**home.js**

```
    $(function(){

      NP.bind("CHANGED", event_handler);

     function event_handler(evt, data ){
       // do something....
     }

     $('#button').click(function(){
      // call my public method in my NP plugin
      NP.PublicMethod();
     });

  });
```

**Closure ( style )**

```
var NP = function(namespace){

     var innerVariable = "the outside scope can't here me";

     finction innerMethod(){
        //does some inner functionality to the closure
     }  

     namespace.PublicMethod = function(){
       // does some calling of inner function.
      // user can access this method from the myplugin directly.
      // example: NP.PublicMethod();
     }

     function actionMethod(){
       // trigger an event so others outside this closure can react
       namespace.trigger("CHANGED");
     }

    }(NP || {});
```

Please if someone can answer the first 3 questions then the larger question about the triggering of events. Thanks in advance

**Update:**

Something that ShankarSangoli made an example of by triggering the event from a DOM element. 
The issue here is I have a dom element that is acting as a close button inside my closer, but home.js has no idea of it or no reference to, nor should it. So I need a way for to listen on the NP object level for events fired from it. As a test I tried the below code and it worked. No idea why as its not a DOM element, but in most languages you can fire an event from most generic objects. And in this case NP is in fact an object, or am I going mad in thinking its an object.

**closure Object**

```
   function actionMethod(){
           // trigger an event so others outside this closure can react
           $(namespace).trigger("CHANGED");
         }
```

home.js

```
$(TWCCP).bind("CLOSED_POPUP", onClosePopup);
```

Now I'm very confused about this. How is this possible now???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, `NP` is in global namespace.
2. Yes, in order to use any method of NP you have to say `NP.methodName();`
3. If set `NP = null` then it will be destroyed and javascript will take care of garbage collection and destroying it inner variable.

You cannot use `NP.bind` unless `NP` is a jquery object associated to a dom element.

The way to trigger any event is as below

```
$("domElementSelector").trigger("click");//Or any otherr event, even custom event like in your case CHANGED can be triggered.
```

For your last part of question try this

**Closure(style)**

```
var NP = function(namespace){

     var innerVariable = "the outside scope can't here me";

     finction innerMethod(){
        //does some inner functionality to the closure
     }  

     namespace.PublicMethod = function(){
       // does some calling of inner function.
      // user can access this method from the myplugin directly.
      // example: NP.PublicMethod();
     }

     function actionMethod(){
       // trigger an event so others outside this closure can react
       $(namespace).trigger("CHANGED");
     }

     namespace.bind = function(eventType, handler)
     {
        $(namespace).bind(eventType, handler);
     }
return namespace;

    }(NP || {});
```

**home.js**

```
$(function(){

      NP.bind("CHANGED", event_handler);

     function event_handler(evt, data ){
       // do something....
     }

     $('#button').click(function(){
      // call my public method in my NP plugin
      NP.PublicMethod();
     });

  });
```

Comment: Thanks ShankarSangoli so how would I be able to listen for any events fired from the NP object itself. There is a close button going to be in the NP object closure and I want to be able to fire a CHANGED event when it happens. Then in my home.js I want to be able to listen for this event and act on with my event_handler() method. What I think you are saying is events can only be fired from a DOM Element, and not from objects itself?

Comment: Please check my edited answer also. Your above code would not work because bindToChangedEvent is local. You would have to use namespace.bindToChangedEvent = function() to call it. Also this is not what I'm asking. I need a way to listen for an event fired from and object not the dome element. home.js has no idea of the dome element that would be firing the event.

Comment: @Chapsterj - Can you try my edited answer now. I hope that will work.

Comment: function event_handler(evt, data ){
       // do something....
     }
is not getting called. if you look at my updated answer it all works correctly. I just need someone to explain why it works now. All I did was wrap my NP is a jquery wrapper. I just don't understand why it works.

Comment: I'm getting no error from your code. I'm just getting now event call to   function event_handler(evt, data ){
       // do something....
     }
See my updated example which works. I just need to know why it works.

Comment: @Chapsterj - Take a look at this fiddle I have made it work now. You can understand the logic from there mean while I will also edit my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/L8VPT/

Comment: Please check my edited answer it works now, return statement was missin in the NP method.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle but your completely misunderstanding my question, or maybe I'm not been clear. I don't need MP to listen for the event I need my home.js to listen for the event. home.js is a completely different js file. It just has a reference to NP closure as its global. Please see my example which is working now. The only problem is I don't know why its working. by just wrapping NP in a Jquery wrapper $(NP)

Comment: Because bind method works on an object as well. If you bind an event on any object and trigger the event on the same object it will fire it.

Comment: NP will maintain the event handlers and whenever you trigger that event it will execute all the handlers attached with this event.

Comment: I just changed your fiddle to look like what I have but more simplified. http://jsfiddle.net/L8VPT/1/

Comment: "Because bind method works on an object as well. If you bind an event on any object and trigger the event on the same object it will fire it."                                                                   Ok that's the answer so it does work on any object. If that's the case why not just the namespace without wrapping it in jquey(). As namespace is an object already

Comment: I took a look at the modified fiddle. In that what is `NP.bind`, it is undefined because of which nothing happens

Comment: `namespace` is just a plain object which do not have any `bind` method. `bind` is a `jquery` method not a native `javascript` method. So in order to use `bind` you have to create a `jquery` object first. I hope this answers your question and you accept this answer :)

Comment: Answer to your last question. NP is the object that is stored in the NP variable which creates the closure

Comment: Ok so that makes sense, Its not about excepting an answer. Its about explaing the answer. Thats what I asked in my first comment. "What I think you are saying is events can only be fired from a DOM Element, and not from objects itself?" This was not the case and events can be fired from any object. Second part answered: Only if the object is a jquery object. Now I understand THANKS

Comment: Yes, it has to be a jquery object because it takes care of custom event handling on the objects.

Comment: Yes Yes Yes I accept your answer. As I said I appreciate your answer.